# Почему считывается первая ветвь if

Tags: python-3.x, if

При вводе любые значений программа входит в первую ветвь и завершает цикл

```
    while counter < len(b):
        user_answers = input()
        user_answer = Player(user_name, user_answers)
        if user_answers == "стоп" or "stop":
            print("Вы остановили игру")
            break
        if (len(user_answers) <= 2):
            print("слишком короткое слово")
        elif user_answers not in b:
            print("неверно")
        elif user_answer.check_repeat == False:
            print("уже использовано")
        else:
            print("верно")
            user_answer.append_to_list
            counter += 1

    print(f'Игра завершена, вы угадали {counter} слов')
    print(our_player.use_word)
```

[image]

Comment: if user_answers == "стоп" or user_answers =="stop": или if user_answers in ["стоп", "stop"]:

Answer (score 2):

В первой ветви у Вас два условия: ответ от пользователя равен слову "стоп" или "stop" это строка. Любая строка возвращает True, если она не пустая. У Вас не правильно сделано условие, нужно сделать так:

```
if user_answers == "стоп" or user_answers == "stop":
    print("Вы остановили игру")
    break
```